# Binary heap на основе linked list

Tags: c

Пытаюсь реализовать Binary heap. У меня получилось сделать добавление до 6 уровня (можно увеличить, но это не важно). Проблема с удалением, в коде я хотел удалять, как в обычном бинарном дереве, но как бы я не менял, постоянно выводит ошибку, либо копирует значения.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define asize 500

typedef struct Binary_Heap{
    int value;
    struct Binary_Heap *left;
    struct Binary_Heap *right;
} Heap;

int op[asize][asize];
int row = 8, col = 2;
int max_level = 3, sum = 0;

Heap* newNode(int value){
    Heap *temp = malloc(sizeof(Heap));
    temp->value = value;
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;
    return temp;
}
int bol = 0;
Heap* add(Heap *root, int k, int value){
    Heap *temp;
    if (bol == 0){
        if (root == NULL){
            root = newNode(value);
            sum++;
        }
        else if (root->left == NULL){
            temp = newNode(value);
            root->left = temp;
            sum++;
        }
        else if (root->right == NULL){
            temp = newNode(value);
            root->right = temp;
            bol = 1;
            sum++;
        }
    }
    return root;
}

int bol2 = 0;
void inorder(Heap *root, int value, int k)
{
    Heap *temp;
    k++;
    if (root != NULL){
        inorder(root->left, value, k);
        if (k == max_level - 1){
            if (root->left == NULL && bol2 == 0){
                temp = newNode(value);
                root->left = temp;
                bol2 = 1;
                sum++;
            }
            else if (root->right == NULL && bol2 == 0){
                temp = newNode(value);
                root->right = temp;
                bol2 = 1;
                sum++;
            }
        }
        inorder(root->right, value, k);
    }
}

Heap* minValue(Heap *root){
    Heap *current = root;
    while (current->left != NULL){
        current = current->left;
    }
    return current;
}

int bol_del = 0;
Heap* delete_value(Heap *root, int value){
    if (root->value == value || bol_del == 1){
        bol_del = 1;
        if (root == NULL){
            return root;
        }
        if (root->left == NULL){
            Heap *temp = root->right;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }
        else if (root->right == NULL){
            Heap *temp = root->left;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }
        Heap *temp = minValue(root->right);
        root->value = temp->value;
        root->right = delete_value(root->right, temp->value);
    }
    else if (root != NULL && bol_del == 0){
        delete_value(root->left, value);
        delete_value(root->right, value);
    }
}

void inTree(Heap *root){
    if (root != NULL){
        inTree(root->left);
        printf("%d ", root->value);
        inTree(root->right);
    }
}

int main(){
    Heap *root = NULL;
    int choice, value;
    while (1){
        printf("\tInsert - 1\n\tInsert2 - 2\n\tinTree - 3\n\tDelete value - 4\n");
        printf("-->");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        if (choice == 1){
            system("cls");
            printf("Enter a value: ");
            scanf("%d", &value);
            bol = 0;
            if (sum < 3){
                root = add(root, 0, value);
            }
            else {
                choice = 2;
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        if (choice == 2){
            if (sum == 7){
                max_level = 4;
            }
            else if (sum == 15){
                max_level = 5;
            }
            else if (sum == 31){
                max_level = 6;
            }
            bol2 = 0;
            inorder(root, value, 0);
            printf("\n");
        }
        else if (choice == 3){
            system("cls");
            inTree(root);
            printf("\n");
        }
        else if (choice == 4){
            system("cls");
            printf("Enter a value: ");
            scanf("%d", &value);
            bol_del = 0;
            delete_value(root, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define asize 500

typedef struct Binary_Heap{
    int value;
    struct Binary_Heap *left;
    struct Binary_Heap *right;
    struct Binary_Heap *prev;
} Heap;

int op[asize][asize], stack[100];
int row = 8, col = 2;
int max_level = 3, sum = 0, first, sec, th;

Heap* newNode(int value){
    Heap *temp = malloc(sizeof(Heap));
    temp->value = value;
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;
    return temp;
}
int bol = 0;
Heap* add(Heap *root, int k, int value){
    Heap *temp;
    if (bol == 0){
        if (root == NULL){
            first = value;
            temp = newNode(value);
            root = temp;
            temp->prev = NULL;
            sum++;
        }
        else if (root->left == NULL){
            sec = value;
            temp = newNode(value);
            root->left = temp;
            temp->prev = root;
            sum++;
        }
        else if (root->right == NULL){
            th = value;
            temp = newNode(value);
            root->right = temp;
            temp->prev = root;
            bol = 1;
            sum++;
        }
    }
    return root;
}
int bol2 = 0;
void inorder(Heap *root, int value, int k)
{
    Heap *temp;
    k++;
    if (root != NULL){
        inorder(root->left, value, k);
        if (k <= max_level - 1){
            if (root->left == NULL && bol2 == 0){
                temp = newNode(value);
                root->left = temp;
                temp->prev = root;
                bol2 = 1;
                sum++;
            }
            else if (root->right == NULL && bol2 == 0){
                temp = newNode(value);
                root->right = temp;
                temp->prev = root;
                bol2 = 1;
                sum++;
            }
        }
        inorder(root->right, value, k);
    }
}

Heap* minValue(Heap *root){
    Heap *current = root;
    while (current->left != NULL){
        current = current->left;
    }
    return current;
}

int bol_del = 0;
Heap* delete_value(Heap *root, int value){
    if (root != NULL){
        int key;
        if (root->value == value){
            if (sum == 1){
                bol_del = 1;
                return NULL;
            }
            else if (root->right != NULL){
                Heap *temp = minValue(root->right);
                while (temp->right != NULL){
                    temp = minValue(temp->right);
                }
                root->value = temp->value;
                key = root->value;
                root = temp->prev;
                if (root->right != NULL && root->right->value == key){
                    temp = root->right;
                    root->right = NULL;
                    free(temp);
                }
                else {
                    temp = root->left;
                    root->left = NULL;
                    free(temp);
                }
                sum--;
            }
            else if (root->left != NULL){
                Heap *temp = root->left;
                root->value = temp->value;
                root->left = NULL;
                free(temp);
                sum--;
            }
            else if (root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL){
                Heap *temp = root->prev;
                key = root->value;
                if (temp->right != NULL && temp->right->value == key){
                    temp->right = NULL;
                }
                else {
                    Heap *node = temp->left;
                    temp->left = NULL;
                }
                sum--;
            }
        }

        delete_value(root->left, value);
        delete_value(root->right, value);
    }
}

void inTree(Heap *root){
    if (root != NULL){
        inTree(root->left);
        printf("%d ", root->value);
        inTree(root->right);
    }
}

void Check_sum(){

    if (sum == 8 ){
        max_level = 4;
    }
    else if (sum == 16){
        max_level = 5;
    }
    else if (sum == 32){
        max_level = 6;
    }
}

int main(){
    Heap *root = NULL;
    int choice, value;
    while (1){
        printf("%d\n", sum);
        printf("\tInsert - 1\n\tInsert2 - 2\n\tinTree - 3\n\tDelete value - 4\n");
        printf("-->");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        if (choice == 1){
            system("cls");
            printf("Enter a value: ");
            scanf("%d", &value);
            bol = 0;
            Check_sum();
            if (sum < 3){
                root = add(root, 0, value);
            }
            else {
                choice = 2;
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        if (choice == 2){
            bol2 = 0;
            inorder(root, value, 0);
            printf("\n");
        }
        else if (choice == 3){
            system("cls");
            inTree(root);
            printf("\n");
        }
        else if (choice == 4){
            system("cls");
            printf("Enter a value: ");
            scanf("%d", &value);
            bol_del = 0;
            delete_value(root, value);
            if (bol_del == 1){
                root = delete_value(root, value);
                sum--;
                bol_del == 0;
            }
            Check_sum();
        }
    }
}
```